# tried exporting my app the process failed and ended up giving me errors in my code

Tags: java, android, import, export, overriding

hey i am new to android development. i tried exporting my app the process failed because of some minor errors and then i got errors all over my code. it was working perfectly fine with no errors before attempting to export.

check these two pics of the xml files where the errors popped up

main activity file: http://postimg.org/image/4gwdipnap/

second activity file: http://postimg.org/image/vuy1ryba3/

I didn't have any of these errors before trying to export the project.

heres the code for both of the files

main activity page

```
package youngadults.camden;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class FrontPage extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front_page);
        findViewById(R.id.uyounadults).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(FrontPage.this, youngadultsp.class);
                 myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(myIntent);

           }
        });
    }
}
```

second activity page

```
package youngadults.camden;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class youngadultsp extends Activity 
{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

setContentView(R.layout.youngadultsp_1);

}


}
```

Comment: someone please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Android API level, do you use `Android Studio` or `Eclipse`?

For Eclipse edit your Manifest file (19 is example):

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
```

For `Android Studio`

1. Right click the App directory
2. Select "Open Module Setting" at the bottom
3. Under Modules select app
4. Set 'Compile Sdk version' as you want

Comment: as i said i am new to android development i don't know a lot. i dont get the steps for eclipse api baseline on the link you provided. could you please explain them in simple words?

Comment: Before you send your application to users, you need to set minimal API level. By doing that, you will tell other what are supported OSs for your application. I added another way (in answer) for setting it in Eclipse.

Comment: i think i already have that line in the manifest file android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"